# Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which the function has a unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let us consider the function 
$$f(x)=αx^{θ}+β$$ where $α>0,β<0,θ>0$.

My **question** is: Find sufficient and necessary conditions in which this function has a unique fixed point in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Note that a fixed point amounts to a solution of $f(x) = x$.  Since $f(x)-x$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, you can use a variety of standard propositions to explore when the function has a unique root in that interval.

Comment: @hardmath: Can you give an example on that methods.

Comment: Try the Intermediate Value Theorem and check values for $f(x)-x$ at the endpoints.

Comment: @hardmath: This result show the existence if $α+β-1>0$ but not the unicity.

Comment: Proving the root is unique amounts to showing the function remains positive after its first root.  So one sufficient condition is $f(x)-x$ increasing on $[0,1]$.  You can think about ways to tighten that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Quoting @hardmath as well since he commented first about a similar way of solving it)

Recall that a fixed point means :

$$f(x_0) = x_0 \Rightarrow ax_0^\theta + \beta = x_0 \Leftrightarrow ax_0^\theta+\beta - x_0 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_0(ax_0^{\theta - 1}-1) + \beta=0$$

Thus all you need to do, is determine when the function :

$$g(x) = x(ax^{\theta - 1}-1) + \beta $$

has a unique solution in the interval $[0,1]$.

The values of $g(x)$ at the end points of the given interval, are :

$$g(0) = \beta$$

$$g(1) = a-1+\beta$$

For the function $g(x)$ to have at least one root in the interval $[0,1]$, one can apply ***Bolzano's Theorem*** since the function is continuous in it. Then, if :

$$g(0) \cdot g(1) < 0 \Rightarrow (a-1+\beta)\beta < 0$$

the function $g(x)$ will have at least one root in $(0,1)$. Since $\beta <0$ then you'll need :

$$a-1+\beta > 0 $$

For this root to be unique, it would be enough if you could show that $g(x)$ is strictly monotonic. Studying the derivative of $g(x)$, we'll have :

$$g'(x) =a\theta x^{\theta-1}-1$$

To be strictly monotonic, you want one of the following, since strictly monotonic means increasing or decreasing in the given interval :

$$g'(x) > 0 \Rightarrow a\theta x^{\theta -1} -1>0 \quad \forall x\in (0,1)$$

$$g'(x) < 0 \Rightarrow a\theta x^{\theta -1} -1<0 \quad \forall x\in (0,1)$$

Joining these $2$ with the first case in $2$ different cases, you'll have sufficient conditions for strictly one root of $g(x)$ in $[0,1]$ or in other words a unique fixed point of $f(x)$, if you can give solutions to the following systems of inequalities for all $x \in (0,1)$ :

$$\begin{cases} a-1+\beta < 0  \\ a\theta x^{\theta -1} -1>0 \end{cases}$$

$$\text{or}$$

$$\begin{cases} a-1+\beta < 0  \\ a\theta x^{\theta -1} -1<0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Your last conditions gives $x>((1/(θα)))^{(1/(θ-1))}$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$ and  this is impossible since the term is positive.

Comment: @ZeraouliaElhadj Hi, why is this impossible ? $\theta, a$ are positive reals which means the root of $\theta-1$ **is** defined and is positive, which also is logical since $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: The problem is with the statement: for all $x$ in $[0,1]$. Notice that not all these numbers are $>((1/(θα)))^{(1/(θ-1))}$

Comment: @ZeraouliaElhadj How is this ? $\theta > 0, a>0$ gives you an infinite combinations of both and you also have another inequality that **must** be true. Also, it's easy to understand that such conditions are necessary and sufficient because both theorems are strict and are cases which prove what we need in an analysis way but involving geometry too in their initial definitions. Also, an approach with the ***Intermediate Value Theorem*** also provides necessary and sufficient conditions and is similar to this one that I've elaborated over.

Comment: Just note that there is one more case to be examined; that of Bolzano's Theorem not being satisfied, however, there is a fixed point of $f$. So, the cases described are not all the cases.

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος True my fellow Greek friend Bill ! Note that Bolzano's inequality could also be $\leq 0$ **only** for finite points ! Then, you'll have to search some more ! But the ones discussed in the solutions **are** sufficient, for example. Reducing such a problem amazingly is not always possible with theorems and that's where numerical analysis and fixed point iterations come !

Comment: I see, I just felt the inner need to mention it, since it has been asked by the OP. Nice answer either way! :)

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Thanks a lot ! Of course, you did well mentioning it ! Χρόνια πολλά !